# if an array default is true, how to display his content?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

if I have an array with the following structure:

```
$currencies = Array (7)
   0 => Array (3)
       id => "11"
       code => "CHF"
       default => "0"
   1 => Array (3)
       id => "13"
       code => "USD"
       default => "0"
   2 => Array (3)
       id => "12"
       code => "EUR"
       default => "1"
```

I would like to retrieve the 'code' when default is equal to '1', something like:

```
if($currencies.default == 1 ){
$currency_code = EUR
}
```

That was just a rough example of my intention, I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: are there going to be more than one array with `default =>1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

First you go through each element with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and filter all those subArrays out, which don't have `default => 1`.

After this just simply grab the column `code` out of the filtered array from before with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), e.g.

```
<?php

   $result = array_column(array_filter($currencies, function($v){
       return $v["default"] == 1;
   }), "code");

   print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => EUR
)
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_column() I am dummy on this :S

Comment: @ValerieCastle Your PHP version (`echo phpversion();`) is under <5.5. So just change out the `array_column()` with `array_map()`, e.g. `$result = array_values(array_map(function($v){
  return $v["code"];
  }, array_filter($currencies, function($v){
     return $v["default"] == 1;
    })));`

Comment: @ValerieCastle So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [**array_filter()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). Example:

```
$result = array_filter($currencies, function($v){return $v['default'] == 1 ? $v['code'] : false;});

print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';
```